# django saving product id when clicking on a button

Tags: django

I have a ListView that displays a list of results (eg products) which are looped through in the template. Each product in the list has a button which the user can choose to select the product.

I would like to store the product id selected by the user in the session so I can use it later. (It will be used in the next view where the user will sign to pay for item and also to pass into external api request to check stock)

What's the best way to store the product id in the session for use later
Currently I tried this in the template:

```
<a class="btn btn-cta-primary" href="{% url 'users:signup' price_id=quote.priceId %}">Proceed</a>
```

Which I thought would pass it to the next view where I could write it to the session with

```
self.request.session['price_id']
```

(perhaps it's best to immediately save it to the session when the button is clicked?)

Comment: yep session is better

Comment: What's the best way to store data in the session from clicking on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to store session. Below is an example to store session using jquery

```
$('#id_of_button').on('click', fucntion(e){
    sessionStorage['product_id'] = 'PRODUCT_ID'
})
```